# Catch the event when a URL Link is tapped within TTStyledTextLabel

Tags: ios, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

I'm working with TTStyledTextLabel and I'm facing the following problems. I do appreciate if you could take a look and support me somehow to fix them.

The app I'm developing has been developed by another developer. It's based on the standard UITableViewController. However, according to the requirement, I have to use TTStyledText inside of the UITableViewCell.

The TTStyledTextLabel is used to display content which might consist of (1) links to websites; or (2) internal links with a parameter, the app will process that parameter to display appropriate content.

The problems I'm facing are:

1. When the TTStyledTextLabel has a link, and user tap on the link, other part of the content is gone, just the link is displayed :( I need the full content remained.
2. I don't know how to catch the tapped URL link for further progress. I need to catch that URL to get the parameter.

I'm quite new to Three20, please give me some clues. Thank you very much!

Best Regards,
Thang

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer my second question (to catch the URL), I implement the TTNavigatorDelegate like this

```c
    - (BOOL)navigator: (TTBaseNavigator *)navigator shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *) URL {
        NSString *query = URL.query;

        //process the query

        return NO;
    }
```

That's works well! However, the first question still remains. When a link is tapped, other texts are disabled :(

Comment: It's because clicking on the label selects the cell. I'm trying to solve the same problem myself.